# Measuring integrated current

Tags: current, amplifier, current-measurement, measurement, transimpedance

I want to measure the amount of light striking a photodiode in a specific time window (about 1ms). In this window, we get \$10^6-10^7\$ photons, which get converted into electrons with about 80% efficiency.

The standard method of performing this measurement is to use a transimpedance amplifier to convert the current into a voltage which is then sampled rapidly throughout the time period and integrated. However, there are lots of places for noise to creep in. Each of the measurements is quite noisy, and this get integrated up.

I was wondering if there was a more accurate method of measuring the total charge produced in this window?

So far I have been considering something like an analog CCD:

- A capacitor is used to store the charge.
- When the time window is over a digital signal can isolate the capacitor from the photodiode
- The charge on the capacitor is then measured, by some method I haven't thought of yet

If anyone has any advice I'd love to hear it. Essentially, I currently have a noisy measurement of the current over time, which I would like to trade for a more accurate measurement of the total charge produced.

Edit:
As some context, this question was brought up when I realised that a single-pixel CCD would actually do this job much better than a photodiode. They can have large quantum efficiencies and read noise in the 10s of electrons. Sadly, single-pixel CCD's don't appear to exist, as far as I can tell. (Also, the dark current is a little problematic, but you can always cool them down).

An avalanche photdiode (or photomultiplier) might also be better suited, but we're trying to avoid high voltage.

Comment: Perhaps this thesis would be useful: Design of High-Resolution Photodiode Readout Circuitry for a Bio-Implantable Continuous Glucose Sensing Chip ( https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid:ea9d2e1c-5b03-44e9-b916-587fd737313f/datastream/OBJ/download )

Comment: Integration tends to reduce noise. It's differentiation that tends to enhance noise.

Comment: The number of photons you need to count is very low, so perhaps the best choice is a [photomultiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomultiplier_tube): however, operating such devices require several cares since they are very high speed and high voltage devices.

Comment: @ThePhoton is right; since you're integrating this, the noise will be reduced, not worsened.

Comment: It appears you want to get down to as low as \$100\:\text{pA}\$ of photogenerated current. What resolution into that do you expect? What noise floor is acceptable? What accuracy do you require (keep in mind that accuracy involves traceability to standards.) What methods of calibration for accuracy do you possess? What repeatability would you require if you built two of these? (How close would you expect their measurements to be, given the exact same measurement situation?) And definitely consider the change in bias currents for opamps over temperature. Scary, not infrequently.

Comment: @jonk Yes, the currents are very small. I did exaggerate slightly, in that the window is often only 100us and there is a significant concentration of the current within the first few 10s of us. Accuracy is not of much concern, as we make relative measurements, but linearity and repeatability are. Ideally, we are aiming for the shot noise limit, so a SNR of about 1000 on the final measurement. Bias current drift:I'll check that out.

Comment: @ThePhoton Perhaps that was unclear. I meant that the total noise increases when you add (integrate) all of the sequential measurements. The SNR does decrease though.

Comment: @Ben34576 Are you integrating an exponential decay, such as might be generated with fluorescence or phosphorescence decay?

Comment: Silicon photomultipliers work down to 20V according to Wikipedia, probably even less in reality. What is a 'low' enough voltage?

Comment: @Ben34576, why are you worried about total noise increasing if SNR is increasing?

Comment: @thePhoton I think I've been unclear. Yes, the integration gives a better SNR than each individual measurement. If I have 100 data points of magnitude 10, each with noise 1, my total SNR goes from 10 to 100 by integrating. However, if I were able to compress that total signal into a single point of magnitude 1000, the SNR could be 1000. That's what I mean, by the noise integrating up. By spreading the signal out in time the total SNR is decreased.

Comment: @HKOB Sorry, I was thinking of photomultiplier tubes. I've not seen Silicon photomultipliers before. They look like they could be suitable. However, they tend to have pretty low detection efficiency at 780nm, where we work.

Comment: @jonk The decay is approximately exponential, yes.

Comment: @Ben34576 So you are looking to find the area under the curve? Or else you are looking to find out how long it takes for a specific area under the curve to take place and work out the \$\tau\$ from that?

Answer (score 1):

> The standard method of performing this measurement is to use a transimpedance amplifier to convert the current into a voltage which is then sampled rapidly throughout the time period and integrated. However, there are lots of places for noise to creep in.

Reducing the places for noise to creep in is exactly why you would want to digitize your signal as soon as possible, and use as few analog processing stages as you can.

> Each of the measurements is quite noisy, and this get integrated up.

Integration will tend to reduce noise, not increase it, because integration is inherently bandwidth-limiting.

It's differentiation that tends to enhance noise.

You can certainly build an integrating response into your transimpedance amplifier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ZLSO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If R1 is very high, then the integrating response provided by C1 will tend to dominate the TIA response, and you will effective have an integrating TIA. In fact, this configuration is often used because the capacitive feedback path can improve the amplifier's stability, even when an integrating response is not desired. The integrating version is essentially just over-compensating this common circuit.

If you need to reset the output, you will need some additional circuitry to discharge C1 (without letting the op-amp go into saturation).